# Como hacer un pinito de navidad en PHP?

Tags: php, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Tengo este codigo que me genera este pino

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero que me salga asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Pinos Examen</h2>

<form action="examenpinos.php" method="post">
  Cantidad de nivel:<br>
  <input type="number" name="nivel" value="nivel">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php
$nivel = $_REQUEST['nivel'];

echo "<center>";
    //Condicion que limita el numero de niveles
    if ($nivel >=1 && $nivel<=9){

for ($k=1; $k<=3; $k++)
{
    for ($j=1; $j<=$nivel; $j++)
    {
        for ($i=1; $i<=$j; $i++)
        {
            echo "*";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $j++;
    }
    $nivel=$nivel+2;
}
    //Imprime el tronco
        echo "***<br>";
        echo "***";
        echo "</center>";
}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: estaba bien el código como texto, como lo tenias antes, por favior regrealo a su forma original

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: revertí tu actualización, poner imágenes en vez de código en formato de texto no es bien visto

Comment: Gracias compañeros, soy nuevo en la pagina y aun intento adaptarme a las normas de la pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código lo he probado y funciona.

He almacenado el valor de la variable `$nivel` en una constante, para comparar donde empezarían los siguientes triángulos y así omitir el salto de línea y el aumento de la variable `$j`.

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Pinos Examen</h2>

<form action="examenpinos.php" method="post">
  Cantidad de nivel:<br>
  <input type="number" name="nivel" value="nivel">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
<?php
  $nivel = $_REQUEST['nivel'];
  define('NIVEL', $_REQUEST['nivel']); //constante para almacenar nivel, sin cambios de valor

  echo "<center>";
  //Condicion que limita el numero de niveles
  if ($nivel >=1 && $nivel<=9){

   for ($k=1; $k<=3; $k++){
     for ($j=1; $j<=$nivel; $j++){
        for ($i=1; $i<=$j; $i++){
            echo "*";
        }
        //según esta orden es el primer asterisco de los 2 ultimos triangulos, a los que no se les hará un salto de línea
        if(constant("NIVEL") != $nivel && $j==1){ 
         }else{
           echo "<br>";
           $j++;
         }
      }
      $nivel=$nivel+2;
    }
  //Imprime el tronco
  echo "***<br>";
  echo "***";
  echo "</center>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesante, muchas gracias!
Cumple con lo que se deseaba, eres grande amigo!

Comment: @EnmanuelCastle De nada, me alegra que te haya ayudado.

Comment: @EnmanuelCastle si esta respuesta soluciono el problema planteado en la pregunta te sugerimos marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.